# How do I get the scroll container for a cell dynamically?

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I am trying to create a custom cell editor that uses a popover to display validation messages.  I need to get the scroll container so the popover can move with the cell if the user scrolls inside of the table.

Currently I am able to get it working by finding the container using a hard coded className.  I believe this className changes depending on if you have pinned columns so hardcoding is less than ideal. Is there a way to get this element either through the ICellEditorParams or by passing something external in through the cellEditorParams in the ColDef?

```
<Popover
        //@ts-ignore
        getPopupContainer={() => document.getElementsByClassName('ag-body-container').item(0)}
        style={{position: 'relative'}}
        placement="top"
        visible={hasErrors}
        title={'Error Has Occurred'}
        content={this.props.errorResults && this.props.errorResults[0] || ''}
     >
```

Comment: Why do you want to control the scroll container? I did not use react version. But I now try to add simple bootstrap popover to my custom cell renderer in angular. And it works fine. It scrolled with the cell where it added. I think you need only specify normal css params for it.

Comment: We don't want to control the scroll container, just use it as reference for where the popup would appear.  As per their api of the component - Parent Node which the popup should be rendered to. Default to body. When position issues happen, try to modify it into scrollable content and position it relative. Example function(triggerNode) () => document.body

Comment: This is a similar issue to what they have in one of the other ag-grid features - https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-context-menu/#popup-parent